# C# Equivalent for PtrToStringChars(String s) function present in vcclr.h

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a native C++ function which I wish to import into my C# project file.

the file is vcclr.h and its present in Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include folder. The function is `PtrToStringChars(string s)`

Is there an equivalent c# function I can use in place of this native C++ function?

Also, if I wish to import this function I need to specify the name of the dll which contains this file. How do I get the name of this dll?

I can see the C++ file containing this function and from there I can see its folder location (absolute and relative path).

Comment: Perhaps if you give us the name of the function?

Comment: Function name is PtrToStringChars(string s) present in the vcclr.h file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that method:

```
string str = "hello".Substring(0, 2); // force not to inline the string
                                      // it would be the same if it was inlined

GCHandle h = GCHandle.Alloc(str, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject(); // Your address

// ch is h
// the unchecked is necessary (technically optional because it's default)
// because Marshal.ReadInt16 reads a signed Int16, while char is more similar
// to an unsigned Int16
char ch = unchecked((char)Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr));
```

or with a little unsafe code (see [fixed Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx)):

```
fixed (char* ptr2 = str)
{
    char ch2 = *ptr2;
}
```

And what if you want **exactly** `PtrToStringChars(...)`? You can't have it... It's defined directly in the `vcclr.h` header as an inline function (in mine lines 37-39 for comments, 40-48 for code).